# Using .data() method in jQote – client-side templating plugin

Tags: jquery, client-side-templating, jqote

For the past few weeks, i have been using [jQote – client-side templating](http://aefxx.com/jquery-plugins/jqote/) plugin to generate html fragments in runtime.

For months i have been using the dom attributes like, id, class, alt to store critical data.

Now, I came to know about `.data()` method in jquery to store and retrieve data.

All over my project i am generating html fragments dynamically using templates.

Now i need to know how can i use .data() in these templates dynamically and store critical data within any dynamically created element.

The template js code is like this,

```
var template = templateCache.idOfTheTemplate; // say its a <li>
for(var i = 0; i < length; i ++){
$("#ulID").jqotepre(template, data);
}
```

Template:

```
<script id="idOfTheTemplate" type="text/template">
<li id="<%=this.id%>">//here i want to use .data() and store the id with different key
<a id="<%=this.id%>" href="#"><%=this.linkName%></a>
</li>
</script>
```

**Solution:**

```
 $("#ulID").jqotepre(template, data);
```

After this line has been executed, that element was available in the DOM.

So, you can just do this,

```
$("#ulID").jqotepre(template, data);
$('#' + data.id).data('liInfo', data);//data.id is the ID of the li element in the DOM
```

Comment: I didn't work with client templates, but if you need store some data into element first what you need -- it find this element, than store data at this element. About how to read/save read here -> http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .data() function in JQuery works on html5 data elements.

Meaning

```
<li id="myId" data-food="value" >
```

Is the same as

```
$("#myId").data('food', 'value');
```

You can read more on html5 data elements at http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

And more on JQuerys data function at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/